# Start the session bus of DBus with Perl Net::DBus

Tags: perl, dbus

I am using Perl and the [Net::DBus](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aDBus) module. I wrote a simple test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyObj;
use Net::DBus::Exporter qw(org.example.Tao);
use base qw(Net::DBus::Object);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $service = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($service, '/MyObj');
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

dbus_method("Hello", ["string"]);

sub Hello {
    return 'Hello';
}

package main;
use Net::DBus;
use Net::DBus::Reactor;

my $bus = Net::DBus->session;
my $service = $bus->export_service("org.example.Tao");
my $object = MyObj->new($service);
my $reactor = Net::DBus::Reactor->main();
$reactor->run();

return 0;
```

I am connecting by ssh and using:

```
Perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Linux example.com 2.6.32.19-0.2.99.17.22250fd-xen #1 SMP 2010-09-13 10:16:50 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
```

When I try to start my `test.pl`, I get the error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed:
Failed to execute dbus-launch to autolaunch D-Bus session
```

This error is raised by this line:

```
my $bus = Net::DBus->session;
```

Google hinted to me about `dbus-launch`. I executed `yum install dbus-x11`.

I try start my test code again and get error in the same line:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: 
dbus-launch failed to autolaunch D-Bus session: 
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

After read manuals, I detect that DBUS session daemon isn't started and my ENV var DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is empty:

```
[root@zion perl]# ps ax|grep dbus|grep -v grep
1019 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system
```

Then I exec:

```
[root@zion perl]# dbus-launch --sh-syntax
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-smHadq6yxV,guid=101ccd74fb75ae501485ed004e2a9043';
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS;
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=5037;
[root@zion perl]# ps ax|grep dbus|grep -v grep
1019 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system
5037 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
```

But DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is same empty.

Question:
I need simple two Perl apps. The first app registers the dbus session service. Another app using my registered service. What is the best and correct way to do it in my environment?

Comment: You were asking three separate questions. Stack Overflow does not work well that way, so I have deleted the last two of them. Please [open new questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for the other topics, see [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6799472/revisions) if you need the text.

Comment: Thanks for the title correction but i am using CentOS, not Fedora. I rollback to revision and remove not important questions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to `eval` dbus-launch output. Like this:

```
$ env | grep DBUS
(empty output; no DBUS session bus launched yet)
$ eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
(empty output; DBUS session bus started, output is evaluated to set shell vars)
$ env | grep DBUS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ZkMjn6B47b,guid=85b2da814a8a061d4e7a55004e35b499
```

Second, you should consider how are you going to use your apps. Try to answer yourself these questions: why are you trying to bind to session bus (which is by definition a bus, associated with an interactive user session)? If this is a system-wide service, it should bind to system bus. If it is a user service, user session manager should take care of starting dbus session bus.