# How to create dbus service from console?

Tags: linux, bash, dbus

There are more or less straightforward ways to emit or listen signals of existing DBus services using tools like dbus-send or dbus-monitor.

How to register service and object from the shell? Expecting something like

```
1> dbus-service --session org.example.Test /Test
  2> qdbus org.example.Test /Test org.example.Test.Call qqq
1> qqq
  2> qdbus org.example.Test /Test org.example.Test.Call www
1> www
```

or like

```
1> dbus-service --argc=2 --session org.example.Test /Test -- /usr/bin/printf "%s Q %s\n"
  2> qdbus org.example.Test /Test org.example.Test.Call qqq ttw
1> qqq Q ttw
  2> qdbus org.example.Test /Test org.example.Test.Call www 111
1> www Q 111
```

Comment: There are so many easier ways of using D-Bus that I don't feel that doing it in the shell is all that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented myself: http://vi-server.org/pub/dbus-shell-service.pl using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799472/start-the-session-bus-of-dbus-with-perl-netdbus) as example.

```
Usage: dbus-shell-service.pl service_name command_line_arguments...
Example:
  dbus-shell-service.pl org.example.Test /usr/bin/printf '%s Q %s\n' &
  qdbus org.example.Test / org.vi_server.DbusShellService.Call2 s1 s2
  s1 Q s2
```